# Android : Unable to write data in Sqllite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to write to an database. I wrote all the code and I created a button that when I press it, the data that I write in EditTexts should be added to the database. But when I press the button to add the data to the database the application crashes.

here is the Main Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button1;
    database database1;
    Button button2, SendData;
    EditText editNOH, Hint;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        database1 = new  database(this);

        button1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        SendData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        editNOH = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        Hint = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        AddData();
        viewAll();

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
            }
        });}
    public void viewAll(){
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Cursor res =  database1.getData();
                if (res.getCount() == 0){
                    showMessage("Error", "Nothing found");
                    return;
                }
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while (res.moveToNext()){
                    buffer.append("NOQ:" + res.getString(0) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("SENTENCE:" + res.getString(1)+ "\n\n");
                }
                showMessage("Data", buffer.toString());
            }
        });}


    public void showMessage(String title, String Message){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(Message);
        builder.show();
    }
    public void AddData(){
        SendData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               boolean isInserted =  database1.insertData(editNOH.getText().toString(), Hint.getText().toString());
                if(isInserted == true){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

here is the data base code:

```
public class database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String Name = "help_answer.db";
    public static final String tName = "hints_table";
    public static final String NOQ = "NOQ;
    public static final String helpSentence = "SENTENCE";

    public database(Context context) {
        super(context, Name, null, 1);
    }

 int a=0;//global
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + tName + " (NOQ INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,, SENTENCE TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tName);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public boolean insertData(String number, String helpS ){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues ContentValues = new ContentValues();
        ContentValues.put(NOQ,number);
        ContentValues.put(helpSentence, helpS);
        long result = db.insert(tName, null, ContentValues);
        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    public Cursor getData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from"+ tName, null);
        return res;
    }
}
```

here is the logcat:

```
                                                         android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table hints_table has no column named SENTENCE (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO hints_table(NQO,SENTENCE) VALUES (?,?)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
                                                                              at com.example.ejhon.puzzlegame.database.insertData(database.java:33)
                                                                              at com.example.ejhon.puzzlegame.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:70)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Add the logcat output message

Comment: where is the logcat ?

Comment: why NUMBER OF QUESTION isnt a vaild column name?

Comment: Obviously enough, because it contains **spaces**!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you do not give space between table name and table keyword.

here,

> tablehints_table

change the code like this,

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + tName + " (NUMBER_OF_QUESTION INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, SENTENCE TEXT)");
    }
```

and remove space from column name of table.

Try above code. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

put spaces in the command. change this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table" + tName + "(NUMBER OF QUESTION INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, SENTENCE TEXT)");
}
```

to this

```
int i=0;//global    
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + tName + " ("+i+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+NOQ+" SENTENCE TEXT);");
    }
```

Comment: That's me who up voted your answer. yea that should work.

Comment: Your logcat say autoincreement is only allowed to intergers. NOQ is string

Comment: yes, you cannot increment a string obviously right? so put some int variable as a primery key.

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: as Simo said put some int variable as primary key

Comment: but I need NOQ to be string

Comment: I tried it; it didnt work, it shows the same errors in logcat

Comment: sorry it doesnt show the same errors in the logcat, I updated it

Comment: change create table to CREATE TABLE

Comment: know ot shows me a diffrent error in the logcat, I updated it

Comment: change public static final String NOQ = "NUMBER OF QUESTION"; to public static final String NOQ = "NOQ";

Comment: in the logcat is written that there is no column named SENTENCE

Comment: and it also shows that there is an error inserting values to NOQ and SENTENCE (string values)

Comment: put a comma (,) before SENTENCE in create table statement.

Comment: Now it writes in the logcat that there is no column named NOQ

Comment: db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + tName + " (NOQ INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,, SENTENCE TEXT);");